# How do I find a Fourier coefficient without using integration?

Tags: integration, fourier-series

[image]

I’ve found that $a= \pi$ , $b= -2$, $C=0$ $d= \pi /2 $

Now I have been told to find $a_0$ without using integration ?

and the answer is $a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\pi -2t ) dt = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{\pi}{4} $

What are they doing here ? I don’t get how it’s done

Comment: What is the geometric interpretation of a Riemann integral ?

Comment: What is the definition of $a_0$? (I would like to know the normalization constant)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro let’s say a Fourier series - $f(t) = a_0 + a_1 \cos t + b_1 \sin t + ....$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_0$ equals $1/\pi$ times the area under the graph over the generic interval. The area is that of the right triangle with sides $\pi$ and $\pi/2.$ This gives

$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\pi\times\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$